# AVD device is stuck at "ANDROID" screen

Tags: android, android-studio, android-virtual-device

I'm trying to launch avd on Android studio, but it is just stuck at initial ANDROID screen:

[image]

**I'm running android-studio 2.3.1 on windows 10 32-bit with JAVA 8 on Intel core 2 duo E7500 2.93 Ghz 3GB DDR2 RAM**

My device info are following:

```
 Name: Pixel_API_24

 CPU/ABI: Google APIs Intel Atom (x86)

 Path: C:\Users\user123\.android\avd\Pixel_API_24.avd

 Target: google_apis [Google APIs] (API level 24)

Skin: pixel

SD Card: 100M

hw.dPad: no

runtime.network.speed: full

hw.accelerometer: yes

hw.device.name: pixel

vm.heapSize: 256

skin.dynamic: yes

hw.device.manufacturer: Google

hw.gps: yes

hw.initialOrientation: Portrait

image.androidVersion.api: 24

hw.audioInput: yes

image.sysdir.1: system-images\android-24\google_apis\x86\

tag.id: google_apis

showDeviceFrame: yes

hw.camera.back: emulated

hw.mainKeys: no

AvdId: Pixel_API_24

hw.camera.front: emulated

hw.lcd.density: 480

avd.ini.displayname: Pixel API 24

hw.gpu.mode: guest

hw.device.hash2: MD5:70f950b0b2b8960d1990af72fb74ad27

hw.ramSize: 768

hw.trackBall: no

hw.battery: yes

hw.cpu.ncore: 1

hw.sdCard: yes

tag.display: Google APIs

runtime.network.latency: none

hw.keyboard: yes

hw.sensors.proximity: yes

disk.dataPartition.size: 800M

hw.sensors.orientation: yes

avd.ini.encoding: UTF-8

hw.gpu.enabled: yes
```

Comment: Perform `adb logcat` and see the logs.

Comment: Make sure your machine (read: PC/laptop) has enough resources to run the emulator.

Comment: 3GB is not ample to run Android Studio efficiently, rest aside an emulator on the top of it. Check your Task Manager, there may not be enough hardware resources left to support emulator.

Comment: Sidenote: who uses 32-bit OS these days? You have a 7th generation Intel machine.

Comment: Android suggests min. 4gb ram for android studio to function properly alternatively you can use eclipse

Comment: Google has officially dropped support of Eclipse for Android development, this happened long ago on November 2nd, 2016. Android Studio is official IDE now. Moreover, this Intel machine is not enough for development purposes.

Comment: It's an old machine.. but what if I upgrade my ram, would it work?

Comment: You need a whole new OS... Having more than 4GB on a 32-bit OS doesn't do you any good. Linux can be a fun learning experience

Answer (score 1):

[image: avd device setup] choose emulator device with least resolution, it uses less space on disk n will start comparatively faster esp if you have less RAM

**Check if the least resolution emulator device starts on your system, If it does  not that means you probably have less RAM than min required**

Atleast 4GB RAM is needed to run Android Studio.

Read more for [System Requirements](https://developer.android.com/studio/index.html#videos) & [Tips for fast emulators - Android Studio](https://publishingfirstandroidapp.blogspot.com/2017/10/tip-how-to-make-android-emulators-fast.html)

Comment: Note: 8 GB is the recommended minimum for Android Studio + emulator

Comment: @cricket_007 
3+1 (for emulator) GB is min while 8GB is recommended

[**link**](https://developer.android.com/studio/index.html)